# Django Rest Framework Patch Request with Image Upload

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to make an endpoint for updating the profile image of a user. However, whenever I make the PATCH request, the profile_image field does not change to the uploaded file. I've tested on postman using form-data and I get the response "Updated completed" but the profile_image field remains null.

views.py

```
class ProfileImageView(APIView):
    parser_classes = [MultiPartParser, FormParser]

    def patch(self, request, user_email, format=None):
        print(request.data)
        profile = ProfileImage.objects.get(user_email=user_email)
        serializer = ProfileImageSerializer(profile, data=request.data, partial=True)
        data = {}
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.update(profile, request.data)
            data["response"] = "Update completed."
            data["user_email"] = user_email
            data["profile_image"] = (
                profile.profile_image.url if profile.profile_image else None
            )
            return Response(serializer.data)
        data["response"] = "Wrong parameters."
        return Response(data)
```

models.py

```
class ProfileImage(models.Model):
    user_email = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to="uploads/",
        height_field=None,
        width_field=None,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
```

serializers.py

```
class ProfileImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ProfileImage
        fields = ["user_email", "profile_image"]
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("api-auth/", include("rest_framework.urls")),
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("register/", RegisterView.as_view(), name="register"),
    path("login/", obtain_auth_token, name="login"),
    path("log/add/", LogView.as_view(), name="log"),
    path("log/all/", LogView.getAll, name="logall"),
    path("log/<str:user_email>/", LogView.getByUserEmail, name="logbyuseremail"),
    path("profile/<str:user_email>/", ProfileView.profile, name="profile"),
    path("edit-profile/<str:user_email>/", ProfileView.as_view(), name="profile"),
    path(
        "profile-image/<str:user_email>/",
        ProfileImageView.getProfileImage,
        name="profile-image",
    ),
    path(
        "edit-profile-image/<str:user_email>/",
        ProfileImageView.as_view(),
        name="profile-image",
    ),
    path("events/", EventView.as_view(), name="events"),
]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

[image]

Comment: Replace serializer.update by serializer.save() inside patch request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.save()` for your serializer instead like this:

```py
if serializer.is_valid():
   try:
       serializer.save()
   except ValueError:
       return Response({"detail": "Serializer is not valid"}, status=400)
   return Response({"detail": "Updated."})
else:
   return Response(serializer.errors)
```

This is also going to return the exact errors from the serializer when you are updating.